# Freeing all RAM in R session without restarting R session?

Tags: r

Is there way to clear more RAM than [`rm(list=ls()); gc()`](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-clear-the-environment-on-RStudio) ?

I expected garbage collection (i.e. `gc()`) to clear all RAM back to the level of RAM that was being used when the R session began, however, I have observed the following on a laptop with 16gb RAM:

```
# Load a large object
large_object <- readRDS("large_object.RDS") 
object.size(large_object)
13899229872 bytes # i.e. ~14 gig

# Clear everything
rm(list=ls(all=T)); gc()

# Load large object again
large_object <- readRDS("large_object.RDS")
```

> Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

I can't explain why there was enough memory the first time, but not the second.

Note: when the R session is restarted (i.e. `.rs.restartR()`), `readRDS("large_object.RDS")`  works again

#### Question

In addition to `rm(list=ls())` and `gc()`, how can more RAM be freed during the current R session, without restarting?

Comment: Can't explain the reason, but for smooth sailing R usually needs twice as much memory, so in your case you would need 32 to do any heavy lifting.

Comment: There are many SO posts: `Google: r clear memory`, best is to re-start R.

Comment: @zx8754 Good rule of thumb! In this particular case thankfully dplyr's `filter()` is the first thing called on the large_object, so from there it reduces very significantly and everything works.  Fair to say chrome and R have not been friends the past few hours! Regarding similar posts, but note above "without restarting" :)

Comment: Oops, sorry, ignored the title and text, just looked at the code!